# mp3 uploads with paperclip gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I'm having some trouble getting a specific mp3 that i've uploaded to play.

I have a Ruby on Rails app and I'm using paperclip to upload the actual mp3.  I'm using a Javascript library (called jp-player). I'm at the point where I know the mp3 file has been uploaded, but i'm not getting it to officially play.  If I hit the `play` button, nothing happens.

My model looks like this:

```
has_attached_file :mp3
  validates_attachment :mp3, :content_type => { :content_type => ["audio/mpeg", "audio/mp3"] }, :file_name => { :matches => [/mp3\Z/] }
```

My controller looks like

```
def create
 @cafe = current_user.cafes.build(cafe_params)

  if @cafe.save
    redirect_to @cafe
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def cafe_params
  params.require(:cafe).permit(:name, :description, :street_address, :state, :editors_note, :website, :image, :mp3)
end
```

My view (I have this as a partial that i'm calling in a different view)

```
#cafe_content
  #jquery_jplayer_1.jp-jplayer
  #jp_container_1.jp-audio
    .jp-type-single
      .jp-gui.jp-interface
        %ul.jp-controls
          %li
            %a.jp-play{:href => "javascript:;", :tabindex => "1"} 
          %li
            %a.jp-pause{:href => "javascript:;", :tabindex => "1"} 
          %li
            %a.jp-mute{:href => "javascript:;", :tabindex => "1", :title => "mute"} 
          %li
            %a.jp-unmute{:href => "javascript:;", :tabindex => "1", :title => "unmute"} 
        .jp-progress
          .jp-seek-bar
            .jp-play-bar
        .jp-time-holder
          .jp-current-time
        .jp-volume-bar
          .jp-volume-bar-value
        .jp-no-solution
          %span Update Required
          To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent version or update your
          = succeed "." do
            %a{:href => "http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/", :target => "_blank"} Flash plugin


:javascript
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
      ready: function () {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
          mp3: "<%= @cafe.mp3.url %>",
        });
      },
      swfPath: "/js",
      supplied: "mp3"
    });
  });
```

Does anyone know if there is anything that I am missing that could get this to properly run?

Answer (score 2):

May be your jp player seeks for absolute path, Instead

```
<%=  @cafe.mp3.url %>
```

Try this

`<%= URI.join(request.url, @cafe.mp3.url) %>`

in your mp3 path,